journalctl logs for ros2: `\r` (carriage return character) ruins json format
I'm looking at a ros2 application in a docker container.  When I use journalctl or docker to view the logs, it is all readable. However, if I try to recover journalctl logs with -o json then they all appear as arrays of ints.  (You can recover the message with "".join(chr(x) for x in MESSAGE) in python.)
A quick check shows that every MESSAGE ends in the \r character, and this is consistent with this report that journalctl can't turn it into json as a result.
I'm speculating that it's ros2 that's including the character, since no other applications are having issues with this. Is there a setting somewhere that ensures ros2 does not include the \r character at the end of its logging?  It's a shame to wreck journalctl structured logging.
